# AWS API Gateway and VPC Blacklist resource policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have a trouble understanding how to make API client to work with VPC blacklist resource policy in AWS API Gateway. I'd like to allow API access from specific VPC only so I enabled IAM auth and created the following resource policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:xxxx: bnsxxhvs4y/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-yyyyyy"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:xxxx:bnsxxhvs4y/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now the question is, how do I write client to access this API? I'm using normal procedure to create signed API request, according to AWS documentation which perfectly works when I'm using e.g. IAM username policy, but I cannot make it working with VPC blacklist. Please advise.